# Calculating the RA and Declination of position straight overhead at given time and lat long

Tags: python, math, astronomy

I would like to know the position directly above a given position on earth at a given time in celestial coordinates (RA and Dec). Is this possible, I haven't been able to find anything useful on the internet.

Comment: Yes it is possible. To find the apparent RA (α) and Dec (δ) for the local zenith at a given time, you have δ = latitude, and hour-angle = 0. To convert the hour-angle to RA, you have hour-angle = 0 = GST + longitude - α. So α = GST + longitude, where GST is Greenwich Apparent Sidereal Time. I am sure you will find python routines to convert time in UTC to Greenwich Apparent Sidereal Time.

Comment: hmm Im not sure Im doing this right since Im getting the wrong answer, but Im following ur formula. I am taking my time as utc_time and converting it to sidereal time using astropys Time.sidereal_time("mean"). After that  I get the RA by doing sidereal_time - longitude. Is that all correct?